# Как автоматически уменьшать размер шрифта при изменении разрешения экрана в bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогает только изменение размера шрифта для лого, но становится не читабельным для ПК. Есть ли еще решение для мобильной верстки?
Спасибо!

Comment: [Медиа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) а так же в гугл рекомендую набрать адаптивная вёрстка и почитать

Comment: да медиа подгружаются из maxcdn - не поменяешь никак..

Comment: переименовал навбар и вынес его отдельно в ксс, пришлось уменьшить шрифт, убрать отступы по сторонам (они идут из за cdn) и пока оставляю как есть, вполне читабельно.

Comment: Ну ок, грузите вы стиль с cdn, сделайте свой style.css и туда делайте свои стили и медиа. Всё равно же куда-то пишите свои стили

Comment: Проблема в том, что cdn в приоритете идет, но если я ставлю первым свой ксс, то вся страница плывет, стало быть надо весь свой ксс перебирать и добавлять и не достающее брать из cdn.. тяжко и небыстро

Comment: не находите что это странно? Видимо просто изначально кривая вёрстка. И в чём принцип cdn? не лучше его утащить оттуда?

Comment: дак это "официальный" шаблон от бутсрап 4) подгружается этот cdn как ксс, править не получилось..

Comment: Так вы его сохраните и подключите